# express.static not handling requests I expect it to

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript

I have this js server file with node and I want to have static js on my page but it won't let me

#### `server.js`

```js
import express from "express";
import fs from 'fs';

const app = express();
const home = fs.readFileSync("/Users/divyanshundley/Documents/TS/public/index.html");

app.use('/static', express.static('/static'));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.redirect('/home'));

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.end(home);
});

app.listen(18209, () => {
    console.log('server running on port 18209   ');
});
```

[image]

#### `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MAIN</title>
    <script src="./index.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="MAINHEADING">Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know what those `/static` in `app.use('/static', express.static('/static'));` do exactly? Both are wrong, by the way.

Comment: First check express-static can work with es6. I think express-static need `__dirname` property which is missing in es6.

Comment: Alternatively, `const __dirname = url.fileURLToPath(new URL('.', import.meta.url));`

Comment: I'm confused maybe due to my own lack of knowledge but are you trying to serve the static html sheet or the java script file? you can just add the JavaScript file in as a `<script>` tag to your html if you want it that way can you not?

Comment: `express.static("/static")` is trying to use a folder in the root of your filesystem. You probably meant `express.static("static")` or some other relative path equivalent. You should also use `<script src="/static/index.js">`

Comment: @Phil thank you now I can get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your static route is `./static/index.js`, because you set a `/static` route in `app.use('/static', express.static('/static'))`.

So use it:

```
src="static/index.js"
```

Or:

```
src="localhost:PORT/static/index.js"
```